# Why is my arraySort in java not working properly?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Write a program that reads numbers from the keyboard into an array of type int[]. You may assume that there will be 50 or fewer entries in the array. Your program allows any number of numbers to be entered, up to 50. The output is to be a two-column list. The first column is a list of the distinct array elements; the second column is the count of the number of occurrences of each element. The list should be sorted on entries in the first column, largest to smallest.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Chapter6Problem6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the numbers for your array.");
        int[][] d = new int [2][50];
        int[] a = new int [50];
        int[] b = new int [50];
        int[] c = new int [50];
        for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++)
        {
            a[index] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        ArraySort object = new ArraySort();  //this is where the issue is
        object.sort(a);
        object.duplicate(a, b);
        object.frequency(a, c);



        for(int index = 0; index < 50; index++) //Manual Array copy
        {
            b[index] = d[0][index];
        }
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 50; x++)  //Manual Array copy
        {
            c[x] = d[1][x];
        }
        for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++)
        {
            for(int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
            {
                System.out.print(d[column][row]);
            }
        }
    }


    public int[] sort(int [] a)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 49; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 49; y++)
            {
                if(a[y] < a[y+1])
                {
                    temp = a[y];
                    a[y] = a[y+1];
                    a[y+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    public int[] duplicate(int [] a, int[] b)
    {
        int y = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 49; x++)
        {
            if(a[x] != a[x+1])
            {
                a[x] = b[y];
                y++;
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
    public int[] frequency(int [] a, int [] c)
    {
        int y = 1;
        int z = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < 49; x++)
        {
            if(a[x] == a[x+1])
            {
                y++;
            }
            if(a[x]!= a[x+1])
            {
                y = c[z];
                z++;
                y = 0;
            }   
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

The code below is currently not working because of the ArraySort part and I have no idea why. 
Also, there is a Manual Array copy issue at the for statements. 
Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What is `ArraySort`?  You haven't shown us where you defined it, so it's hard to say why it might not be working.

Comment: It looks like you wanted `Chapter6Problem6 object = new Chapter6Problem6();` instead, since that's what you named your class.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What exactly is the problem you are facing? What is stored in a, b, and c? What are those three calls on ArraySort supposed to do and what do they actually do? (try printing the values after the calls to ArraySort)

Answer (score 0):

**The methods that take a Comparator are for object arrays.**

> So With primitive type arrays of int, you can not do this with `ArraySort`.

You can change your `int[] a = new int [50]` into `Integer[]` and then it will work hope so.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give you a helping hand, but bear with me since this is not an easy task.

### ArraySort Part:

```
ArraySort object = new ArraySort();
```

This line does not make that much a sense here. Why? Because either your class you are refering to is not part of the your post or this should be:

```
Chapter6Problem6 object = new Chapter6Problem6();
```

like [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) said as a comment.
Next thing which is a bit odd here is that you are returning an arrays in each of these methods:

```
public int[] sort(int [] a)
public int[] duplicate(int [] a, int[] b)
public int[] frequency(int [] a, int [] c)
```

Since you are doing stuff inside of these methods or more likely input your results as input parameter this is not neccassary.
Change your methods to

```
public void sort(int [] a)
public void duplicate(int [] a, int[] b)
public void frequency(int [] a, int [] c)
```

and you are good to go here. If you change your return-type to `void` there is no need in returning anything in your methods then.

### Manual Array Copy Part

There should be an exception thrown on the manual copy part because there are no values in the arrays you trying to copy from. You declared and initialized them by didn't assign an value to them. I cannot recall if the values of an initialized array were set to 0 because you are using the type `int` or should be `null` anyhow at which the `null`-case should be very unlikly. Maybe someone else know more about this.

All in all you should take a closer look at the arrays. Which one are you using and which one are still unfilled with actual data from the input.

---

Since this is my first answer and english is not my mothertongue please excuse my perhaps misleading grammar or spelling.